# how do i get the content of this div using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, qtip

i want to show a tooltip when i highlight over any text inside of "**class=div**".  I have the following HTML:

```
<div class='test'>Test</div>
<div class='tooltip'>Tooltip 1</div>

<div class='test'>Test 2</div>
<div class='tooltip'>Tooltip 2</div>

<div class='test'>Test 4</div>
<div class='tooltip'>Tooltip 4</div>
```

and the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('div.test').each(function () {

                var tooltipHtml = //NEED to figure out how get the html of the Tooltip div below this current div
                $(this).qtip({
                    content: {
                        text: tooltipHtml
                    },
                    style: { width: 450 }
                });
            });
        });
```

How do i get the html from the "next" tooltip div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1: Use jQuery [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select it.

```
var tooltipHtml = $(this).next('.tooltip').html();
```

Comment: i seperated the questions into two different questions

Comment: Ok, I'll remove that part then.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a tooltip why not do it like this:

```
<div class="test" title="Tooltip 1">Test 1</div>
<div class="test" title="Tooltip 2">Test 2</div>
<div class="test" title="Tooltip 4">Test 4</div>

<script>
$('.test[title]').qtip({ style: { name: 'cream', tip: true } })
</script>
```

qTip automatically uses the title attribute if no content is set.